# Closed - Removed language -> language routing broken

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Unfortunately I have a weird issue in my PrestaShop (1.6.1.6.).

- My theme came with English and Arabic pre-installed.
- I deactivated and removed Arabic and added German afterwards.
- Then I filled in the first German content.
- Now I realized an error on product pages, CMS pages etc.: I cannot use the language switch anymore. When I click the language flags -> a 404 error comes. up
- What is very strange as well: In the backend English has ID 1 now. German got ID 3. There is no ID 2 anymore. If I add another language it has ID 4.

Does anyone know how to solve that issue?
Nothing from former posts here or what can be found through google has worked for my so far (generate a new .htaccess, install German again, check mod_rewrite, enable / disable Smarty Cache).

Comment: Something similar happened to me buying Hosting with PrestaShop already installed and optimized .
- Clear cache .
- Cancel themes /[ theme -name]/cache.
- Import the German again.
- Again the htaccess Regenerate (after this) .

Comment: Have you tried debugging that switch feature? If so, you should include your finds here.

Comment: @MatteoEnna: Thanks a lot! I will try it out asap. But I guess I do not really understand the second step yet. What do I have to do here exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I will use one of my backups now and start over again.

Comment: After quite a while I found the reason: The problem occurred due to an incompatible SEO plug-in. I had to use a different one from another programmer.